# Catching events on elements created dynamically with PHP

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made a webpage "`items.php`" to which I added a hidden `<p>` element that has the contents of the URL GET parameter passed to the page. Then I made it so on `document.ready` I call a `setup()` function immediately. (This is in `items.js` which is added in a `script` tag at the bottom of `items.php`)

This setup function reads the contents of this hidden `<p>` element  and makes an ajax call and the data echoed in the php is added in the made container (`<div>`) of the page. (Requests to the databases are made and checkboxes are made based on this hidden `<p>` and other input data is generated as well).

Now here is the problem:

From a visual standpoint everything is on point (I made some color checkboxes of my own, div elements) ALMOST. My jQuery UI range sliders aren't there.

Also, events to the created markup I cannot catch in my `items.js`. I am supposed to have a toggle happen on a click on my colored checkboxes I created. Now, all this worked when data wasn't dynamically generated, but now it does not. I even added the listeners after the setup function like so, for example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setup();
  $(".colorbox" ).click(function(){
    $(this).children().toggle();
  });    
});
```

This is my javascript. I cannot get the custom event to trigger:

```
function setup() {
    var determinant = $("#cat").text();
    $.post('../phpdatabase/setup.php', {
        categorija: determinant
    }, function(data) {
        $('#content').empty();
        $('#content').append(data);
    });
};



$(document).ready(function() {
    setup();
    $('body').on('click', '.colorbox', function() {
        $(this).children().toggle();
    });
    $('body').on('myCustomEvent', '#slider-range2', function() {
    alert("hye!");
     });
    $('body').trigger('myCustomEvent');

});
```

myCustomEvent isn't being triggered. Without the second argument, in the handler, it is triggered.

Comment: Where's the `php` code ?

Comment: why use ajax if you are loading the data at page load?

Comment: How to add content dynamically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach the event to the `body` and then the selector you want.. This will work for all elements with class `'.colorbox'` in the `body`, whether already present or dynamically added later.

Code:

```
$('body').on('click', '.colorbox', function(){
   $(this).children().toggle();
});
```

For the  jQuery UI Slider you can also create your own event `'elements-created-dynamically-with-php'` and fire it when you add the dynamic content.

Attach event handler:

```
$('body').on('elements-created-dynamically-with-php', '#slider-range2', function () {
  var $slider = $(this),
      $amount1 = $('#amount1');

  $slider.slider({
    range: true,
    min: 0,
    max: 400,
    values: [0, 400],
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $amount1.val(ui.values[0] + 'cm' + ' - ' + ui.values[1] + 'cm');
    }
  });

  $amount1.val($slider.slider('values', 0) + 'cm - ' + $slider.slider('values', 1) + 'cm');
});
```

And when the content is added fire the event:

```
$('body').trigger('elements-created-dynamically-with-php');
```

Comment: Some sort of explanation would be nice.

Comment: I have updated the solution.. Hope it helps

Comment: That looks great! I already up voted you, GL!

Comment: it is not working for me. Could the problem lay in that the element with id `#amount1` is also dynamically generated?

Comment: My event isn't triggering. I added in the question some sample code on custom events. Much simpler, not triggering.